# Let $\mu(X)=1$, $0 \leq f \leq k$, and $m=\int_X f d\mu$. Show $\int_X |f-m|^2 d\mu \leq \frac{k^2}{4}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu(X)=1$ for $\mu$ a positive measure. Let $0 \leq f \leq k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $m=\int_X f d\mu$. Show $\int_X |f-m|^2 d\mu \leq \frac{k^2}{4}$.

My attempt:

I tried to expand the integrand to see where it would take me. In general, we have $|a|^2=a^2$, so then $|f-m|^2=(f-m)^2=f^2-2fm+m^2$. Thus,
$$ \int_X |f-m|^2 d\mu = \int_X f^2 d\mu - 2m\int_X f d\mu + \int_X m^2 d\mu$$
$$ = \int_X f^2 d\mu - 2m^2 + m^2 = \int_X f^2 d\mu -m^2. $$
I thought about using the fact that $f\leq k$ to obtain
$$ \int_X f^2 d\mu -m^2 \leq k^2 - m^2, $$
but I do not think it is true that $k^2 - m^2 \leq \frac{k^2}{4}$, because that would require $k\leq m\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}$.

That means that I need a tighter bound on $\int_X f^2 d\mu - m^2$. If I can show that
$$ \int_X f^2 d\mu \leq \frac{k^2}{4} + m^2 $$
then I am done, but I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: This is really a result in probability. See [Popoviciu's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances) whose proof is given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588/variance-of-a-bounded-random-variable)

Comment: I have essentially no background in probability so I am not quite sure how that relates to integration.

Comment: In your setup $f$ is a random variable on the sample space $X$, $m=Ef$ and $\int_X|f-m|^2 \,d\mu =\text{Var}(f)=\sigma^2$. Also in general if $g$ is any function on $X$ in your setup $Eg=\int_X g\, d\mu$ See Chapter 10 of Folland's Real Analysis Book for the translations between measure theory and probability theory if this is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: write the integrand as $\left((f-\frac{k}{2}) - (m - \frac{k}{2})\right)^2$.  By expanding you should be able to show that
$$\int_X (f-m)^2\,d\mu = \int \left(f-\frac{k}{2}\right)^2\,d\mu - \left(m-\frac{k}{2}\right)^2 \le \int \left(f-\frac{k}{2}\right)^2\,d\mu.$$
But we have $|f - \frac{k}{2}| \le \frac{k}{2}$...

Answer (score 1):

The point $(\int_X f d\mu,\int_X f^2d\mu)=(m,\sigma^2+m^2)\in\mathbb R^2$ is in the convex hull of the set of points of form $(a,a^2)$ for $a\in[0,k]$. This convex hull has two boundary pieces: a parabolic segment below and the chord connecting $(0,0)$ to $(k,k^2)$ above.  That chord has slope $k$, and so $m^2\le\sigma^2+m^2\le km$. Thus $\sigma^2\le km-m^2 = k^2t(1-t)$ where $t=m/k\in[0,1].$  By calculus (say) we know $t(1-t)\le 1/4$.